# Manipulate iframe of different website (origin policy)

Tags: apache, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have a iframe that links to a website in a different server, I'm receiving this error:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.domain1.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.domain2.org". Protocols, domains, and ports must match
```

How can I make this go away? I need to manipulate the DOM of the iframe.

I have access to the iframed server, should I configure something else besides...

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "www.domain1.net"
```

...to allow access from the domain1.net server?